# Keeping Music on when moniter closed

Tags: helpfile

How do I keep Pithos playing when I close my laptop? I have looked in to settings with the background, screen, brightness, pretty much with anything involving my screen. I have Edge Ubuntu 14, and a dell laptop if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can desactivate the computer hibernation in your settings. So when you close your laptop he just set screen brightness at 0 and your task keep running. I doing that for download with closed laptop. That work pretty well.